# Could Java(Scala) blocking queue allows queue jumper(higher priority)?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, blocking

One could use `LinkedBlockingQueue` to block the operations. Suppose I have only 1 element in queue, and every one could use it.

```
val q = new LinkedBlockingQueue() // 1 element in it
def fun() = {
  val instance = q.take()
  // do some operations
}
def foo() = {
  val instance = q.take()
  // do some operations
}
// Use 3 threads to run following 3 methods, and the order they call q.take() is following
fun()
fun() // will wait for first fun()
foo() // will wait for second fun()
```

And the sequential order these methods finish is `fun(), fun(), foo()`

However, now I want to set `foo` to higher priority, which means allow it to be queue-jumper. That the `foo` could take instance before the second `fun()`(while the second `fun` is waiting, `foo` jumps to the front of it)

And the order they finish could become `fun(), foo(), fun()`, (the first `fun` would take the instance because the instance is available, and second should wait, then the `foo` also wait, but jumped to the front of second `fun`)

Is is possible? Or is there any other data structure possible for this

Comment: You're trying to enforce order when using multiple threads and a `BlockingQueue`? Is this a bad idea for a homework you're supposed to do, or are you completely misunderstanding the purpose of a `BlockingQueue` and threads? You shouldn't be talking about "sequential order" and "multiple threads" in the same sentence. If you just want sequential order, make it single threaded.

Comment: I think `BlockingQueue` is not designed for this, but it is convenient to describe the purpose. And I think another data structure is needed but I do not know who it is

Comment: Then you can't have your "task processors" take the tasks. You need to distribute the tasks according to processor priority.

Comment: So there is no built-in classes could do this? Actually I have parallel tasks, and one stage of them is an OpenMP execution `foo()` which is highest priority and should use all the resources, and during this execution I want to block all other threads `fun()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know of any built-in tool for this task, but it wouldn’t be too hard to implement. Since you only want to exchange a single element, you don’t need a queue but an exchanger.

A simple implementation could look like

```java
class SingleElementExchanger<T> {
    int priorityConsumer;
    T value;

    public synchronized void set(T newValue) throws InterruptedException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(newValue);
        while(value != null) wait();
        value = newValue;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized T ordinaryGet() throws InterruptedException {
        while(priorityConsumer != 0 || value == null) wait();
        T received = value;
        value = null;
        notifyAll();
        return received;
    }

    public synchronized T priorityGet() throws InterruptedException {
        priorityConsumer++;
        try {
            while(value == null) wait();
            T received = value;
            value = null;
            notifyAll();
            return received;
        }
        finally {
            priorityConsumer--;
        }
    }
}
```

For your two ordinary consumers and one priority consumer and a small number of producers, this might already be sufficient.

For a larger number of threads, you might want to use a `Lock`, to be able to notify the right party instead of using `notifyAll()`.

```java
class SingleElementExchanger<T> {
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition empty = lock.newCondition(),
        fullNoPri = lock.newCondition(), fullPri = lock.newCondition();

    int priorityConsumer;
    T value;

    public void set(T newValue) throws InterruptedException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(newValue);
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while(value != null) empty.await();
            value = newValue;
            (priorityConsumer==0? fullNoPri: fullPri).signal();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public T ordinaryGet() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while(priorityConsumer != 0 || value == null) fullNoPri.await();
            T received = value;
            value = null;
            empty.signal();
            return received;
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public T priorityGet() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            priorityConsumer++;
            while(value == null) fullPri.await();
            T received = value;
            value = null;
            empty.signal();
            return received;
        }
        finally {
            priorityConsumer--;
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up CompletableFuture for your purpose. This way you can achieve task ordering.

```
CompletableFuture<String> text = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    return "";
}).thenApply(param -> {
    return "";
}).thenApply(param -> {
    return "";
});
```